# How to run all unit tests for iOS workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, command-line-interface, xcodebuild

I have one host iOS project named `MyProject` under workspace named `MyWorkspace`. The workspace also have two linked projects named `MyFramework1` and `MyFramework2`. When I run unit test only host project's (i.e. `MyProject's`) unit tests are getting run but I have unit tests for both frameworks. How can I run all the unit tests for all projects (including host app and frameworks) under workspace `MyWorkspace` from CLI `xcodebuild` command?

I am currently using,

```
xcodebuild -xctestrun some.xctestrun -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11" test-without-building
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I am able to run all tests for my workspace. I just needed to,

1. Open workspace in Xcode
2. Select Host app Target -> Edit Scheme -> Build
3. Enable test for all unit test suites showing in the list
4. Have a clean build and test